# Не применяются стили к классу .active

Tags: javascript, css, tab

Создан блог табуляции

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
 $(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
 $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
 $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active"); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
 padding-top: 0;
}

.wrapper .tabs {
 border: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.wrapper .tabs .active {
 background-color: #43ac2d;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab {
 display: inline;
 height: 35px;
 padding-top: 4px;
 background-image: url(../img/triangle.png);
 background-position: 25% center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 font-size: em(18px);
 font-family: "ZurichBT-Roman", sans-serif;
 color: #444137;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
 border-left: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
 border-right: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab .tab__title {
 padding-left: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
       <div class="tabs">
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 tab">
          <div class="tab__title">By Destination</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 tab">
          <div class="tab__title">By Species</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4 tab">
          <div class="tab__title">By Tour Type</div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="tab_content">
<!--tab 1-->
        <div class="tab_item">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
            <b>Africa Holidays</b>
            <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
            <b>Americas Holidays</b>
            <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
            <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
            <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
           </article>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
            <b>Asia Holidays</b>
            <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
            <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
            <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
            <b>Europe Holidays</b>
            <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
         </div>  
        </div>

<!--tab 2-->
        <div class="tab_item">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
            <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
            <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
            <b>Americas Holidays</b>
            <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
            <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
            <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
           </article>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
            <b>Africa Holidays</b>
            <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
            <b>Asia Holidays</b>
            <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
            <b>Europe Holidays</b>
            <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
         </div>  
        </div>
<!--tab 3-->
        <div class="tab_item">
         <div class="row">          
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
            <b>Americas Holidays</b>
            <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
            <b>Asia Holidays</b>
            <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
            <b>Africa Holidays</b>
            <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
         </div>  
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
            <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
            <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
           </article>
          </div>          
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
            <b>Europe Holidays</b>
            <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
           </article>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
           <article>
            <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
            <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
            <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
           </article>
          </div>         
          
         </div>  
        </div>        
       </div>
      </div>
```

в итоге без .active все хорошо. Данный class создается JS.
При этом .active нарушает по левому и правому краям: padding и border-radius не применяются.

update:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

update 2:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tab_item").not(":first").hide();
 $(".wrapper .tab").click(function() {
 $(".wrapper .tab").removeClass("active").eq($(this).index()).addClass("active");
 $(".tab_item").hide().eq($(this).index()).fadeIn()
}).eq(0).addClass("active"); 
});
```

```css
.wrapper .tabs {
  border: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab.active {
  background-color: #43ac2d;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab {
  height: 35px;
  font-family: "ZurichBT-Roman", sans-serif;
  color: #444137;
 text-align:center;
}

.wrapper .tabs .tab:nth-child(2) {
  border-left: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
  border-right: 1px #cfcdc5 solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper container">
  <div class="tabs">
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tab">
    <div class="tab__title"><p>By Destination </p></div>
  </div> 
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tab">
    <div class="tab__title"><p>By Species </p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 tab">
    <div class="tab__title"><p>By Tour Type</p></div> 
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab_content">
<!--tab 1-->
<div class="tab_item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
        <b>Africa Holidays</b>
        <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
      </article> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
        <b>Americas Holidays</b>
        <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
        <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
        <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
        <b>Asia Holidays</b>
        <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
        <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
        <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
        <b>Europe Holidays</b>
        <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--tab 2-->
<div class="tab_item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
        <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
        <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
        <b>Americas Holidays</b>
        <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
        <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
        <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
        <b>Africa Holidays</b>
        <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
        <b>Asia Holidays</b>
        <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
      </article>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
        <b>Europe Holidays</b>
        <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!--tab 3-->
<div class="tab_item">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/americas.jpg" alt="americas holiday">
        <b>Americas Holidays</b>
        <p>North, South and Central America are <br>home to an incredible diversity of <br>habitats and species, providing <br>opportunities for wildlife holidays to suit all tastes. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/asia.jpg" alt="asia holidays">
        <b>Asia Holidays</b>
        <p>Choose a Naturetour wildlife holiday to <br>Asia and benefit from our experience of <br>over 20 years, and amazing network of <br>local contacts, on this incredibly diverse continent.</p>
      </article> 
    </div> 

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/elephants.jpg" alt="elephants">
        <b>Africa Holidays</b>
        <p>Few wildlife enthusiasts can resist <br> Africa. Its exceptional abundance and <br>variety of wild animals make it one of the <br> world’s top wildlife holiday destinations.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/antarctica.jpg" alt="antarctica holidays">
        <b>Antarctica Holidays</b>
        <p>The ‘Great White Continent’ is perhaps <br>the last true wilderness left on earth and <br> ultimate wildlife holiday destination. </p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/europe.jpg" alt="europe holidays">
        <b>Europe Holidays</b>
        <p>Naturetour wildlife holidays in Europe <br>focus on the outstanding wildlife habitats <br>and species that can be found in the <br>region.</p>
      </article>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <article>
        <img src="img/australasia.jpg" alt="australia holidays">
        <b>Australasia Holidays</b>
        <p>Australia and New Zealand offer <br>extraordinary wildlife in safe, peaceful <br>surroundings. Our tours focus on this <br>continent's unique flora and fauna.</p>
      </article>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
  </div>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Не знаю понял правильно или нет, просто и нечего не написано, что нужно сделать, но сделал так (методом интуиция)

Comment: Есть меню (переключение табов) - оно имеет border-radius по краям. Между пунктами меню нет промежутков. В тему добавил картинку с разъяснением.

Comment: Я подключил bootsrap и все корректно работает, если вы без bootstrap'a, то .wrapper .tabs .tab {  display: inline-block;  float:left; width: 33.33333%} и нету padding

Comment: @Miroslav я поправил посмотри, приеду домой с рааоты тогда подумаю если что-то не так

Comment: правились js и css или в html тоже правки вносились?

Comment: использую сетку бутстрап

Comment: правил только css

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46998/discussion-between-miroslav-and-lieutenant-jim-dangle).

Comment: http://codepen.io/geek_of_cola/pen/rrqvPZ вот я сделал так